# discord.py give rank for custom status

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I have an idea but unfortunately, I don't know how to make this, or if this is possible.

I want that my discord bot gives a rank on my server for a specific keyword in the custom status. The rank should be removed if the custom status gets removed.

My question is: Is this possible and how can I make a feature like that in python?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. You can use [`discord.Member.activity`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member.activity). It returns a string of member's custom activity. So basically, you can check if the activity contains a specific keyword, if it is then you can add role to member. You can create a task for this to check members' custom activity periodically.

```
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(role id)
    [await member.add_roles(role) for member in client.get_all_members() if 'specific keyword' in member.activity]

check_activity.start()
```

**EDIT**

If you just want to give role to online members, you can use `member.status`. It returns **online** or **offline** or **dnd(do not disturb)**.

Also, you can create a txt file to store all the members that you give that role and you can check again if they still have the specific keywords in their activity.

```py
@tasks.loop(seconds=120)
async def check_activity():
    role = client.guilds[0].get_role(role id)
    file = open('role_members.txt', 'r')
    member_list = [str(member.id) for member in client.get_all_members() if not str(member.status) == 'offline' and 'specific keyword' in member.activity]
    for line in file.readlines():
        if line[:-1] not in member_list:
            member = await client.guilds[0].get_member(int(line))
            await member.remove_roles(role)
    a_file = open('role_members.txt', 'a')
    for member_id in member_list:
        await client.guilds[0].get_member(int(member_id)).add_roles(role)
        a_file.write(member_id + '\n')
            
        
check_activity.start()
```

Comment: So for setting the role, must i just change "member.add_roles(role)" to "member.add_roles(ROLE-ID-HERE)" ?

Comment: It's my bad. You have to define role. Is your bot on only 1 guild or is it on multiple guilds?

Comment: Is it on only 1 guild.

Comment: gets this role automatically removed if the member removes the keyword from his status?
Maybe you can please add this and this should not detect discord statuses from offline users.

Comment: I get this error at startup: https://pastebin.com/wk9cFJBf

Comment: Can you check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619897/mass-dm-bot-was-working-fine-and-now-it-wont-send-messages/64620280#64620280)?

Comment: sadly, that doesn't help. I already activated it in the developer panel and tried this method.

Comment: I fixed it now by setting role = ID-HERE.

But now i have the problem: https://pastebin.com/FhFJCtnX
TypeError: argument of type 'Activity' is not iterable

Comment: Do `str(member.activity)`.

Comment: Fixed it, thanks!
New error: https://pastebin.com/PymVQTxQ
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'