# How do I get a list of all users in my discord server with a specific role using discord async in python? (code inside)

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I have python code that controls a bot in my server that was working until a couple weeks ago. I have code below that would get a list of all the people in the server with a specific role and add them to a list. I then do things with this list later. Code below:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def getuserlist(ctx, useDiscordID : bool = False):   
memberlist = []
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        for member in guild.members:            
            for role in member.roles: 
                if role.name == "something" or role.name == "somethingelse":
                    if member.nick is None:
                        toAppend = member.name
                    else:
                        toAppend = member.nick
                    memberlist.append(str(toAppend))
```

For some reason, this stopped working and instead of getting all users with the something/somethingelse role, it only grabs the users in any voice channel in the server at the time. How do I fix this?

Comment: Did you define the intents?

Comment: @Nurqm I just looked up those and turned them both on in the discord bot options but it still doesnt work. Does it take a while to change? My bot is also only in 1 server, does that matter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably because of the discord.py 1.5.x `Intents` update. If it's the problem, you can look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619897/mass-dm-bot-was-working-fine-and-now-it-wont-send-messages/64620280#64620280) answer.

You can just use [`role.members`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role.members) to get the list of the members that has this role. If your bot runs on only 1 guild, you can do:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def getuserlist(ctx, useDiscordID: bool = False):   
    role1 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='something')
    role2 = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.roles, name='somethingelse')
    memberlist = role1.members + role2.members
```

If it runs on multiple guilds:

```
@bot.command(pass_context = True)
async def getuserlist(ctx, useDiscordID: bool = False):
    memberlist = []
    for guild in bot.guilds:
        role1 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='something')
        role2 = discord.utils.get(guild.roles, name='somethingelse')
        if role1:
            memberlist += role1.members
        if role2:
            memberlist += role2.members
```

Comment: I get the error "discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Member' and 'Member'". This error occurs when I try to memberlist.sort() to organize it. I want to sort it and loop through it later to compare names with those in a voice channel.


My goal is to have a list in the format list = ["discord nickname1, discord nickname2"] etc...

Comment: Edit: got it working by adding nicknames to my list instead of the direct id, thanks.