# On_member_join and on_member_remove events do not work

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

I have tried to make a Discord bot which prints the user joining or leaving to the console. However it seems like it's not triggering my Bot. Here's my code:

Here is my current code

````py
    import discord 
    from discord.ext import commands
    
    client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')
    
    @client.event
    async def on_ready():
      print("Bot is ready")


    @client.event
    async def on_member_join():
      print("{member} hat den Server betreten.")

   ```@client.event
   async def on_member_remove():
      print("{member} hat den Server verlassen.")

  
   client.run('My Token')
````

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mass DM bot was working fine and now it wont send messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619897/mass-dm-bot-was-working-fine-and-now-it-wont-send-messages)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events that use `on_member_join` or others related to member events, must require member intents to be enabled. This works to allow these events to run as they are private and should be used carefully.

Intents can be enabled from Discord developer portal, from there you only need to make sure you have enabled `Member` in intents within the "Bot" category. You'd then need to define and use the intents in your bot code in the section you define your bot or client:

```
intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='your bot prefix', intents=intents)
```