# Discord bot that returns guild owner's username discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Hello guys im trying to write a code that gives me the discord server owner but its giving Me 'None'

```
import discord

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = 'token'

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.find("getowner") != -1:
        await message.channel.send(str(message.guild.owner))


client.run(TOKEN)
```

Can someone please help me with this bot thanks!!
I want to get the discord servers owner by typing getowner in a text channel.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mass DM bot was working fine and now it wont send messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64619897/mass-dm-bot-was-working-fine-and-now-it-wont-send-messages)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using it as a command rather than doing `on_message`, you can do this:

```
from discord.ext import commands

token = "Token"
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!") #Use any prefix

@client.command(pass_context=True)
async def getOwner(ctx):
    #await ctx.channel.send(str(ctx.guild.owner.display_name))
    await ctx.channel.send(str(ctx.guild.owner))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

But if you don't want to use a command, you could use regular expression and just keep it as:

```
import discord
import re

client = discord.Client()
TOKEN = 'token'

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if re.match("getowner", ctx.content):
        await ctx.channel.send(str(ctx.guild.owner))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

EDIT: Also try using `intents` with your bot code.

```
import discord
import re

intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True

client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
TOKEN = "token"

@client.event
async def on_message(ctx):
    if re.match("getowner", ctx.content):
        await ctx.channel.send(str(ctx.guild.owner))

client.run(TOKEN)
```

Same changes can be done with the command version.

Comment: yes thanks for your help but its returning me None!! instead of the server owners username

Comment: Try using `intents` in your code, like in the edit

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple;

```py
from discord.ext import commands

@client.command(name="getowner")
async def getowner(ctx):
   await ctx.send(str(ctx.guild.owner))
```